# Writing data from serial monitor arduino to php server(no ethernet shield)

Tags: php, arduino, wamp

I have a sensor connected to my arduino UNO and I want to display the values from the serail monitor to php server(wamp).Displaying the values is what I want.If someone could tell me how to store it in database would also be fine.I don't know what code to put here.Ask me whatever code you want inorder to answer this question.I don't have an ethernet shield

Comment: you can use php serial class in linux http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17926.html. or here: https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial .    for windows, i think you have to make an app to receive serial data from com port and put it into database.

Comment: I am using windows.What app should I make to receive serial data?

Comment: FYI, i have tried to read gmail from arduino in linux, i have never tried it on windows. you may use any language(you know) to develop the app. Here is a tutorial http://esperimenti-arduino.blogspot.com/p/processing-mysql.html the app is developed using processing language. please post here your code, how far you have tried and be specific to what is your problem so that we can help you. thanks